# How to set IIS online?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I have just installed IIS7 on my Windows 7. Now, I am able to access it via `http://localhost/` and `http://192.168.1.6` on my PC directly.

But, I can't access it from other PC on my local network with `http://192.168.1.6`. What do I need to do to make the IIS online to other PC locally?

Thank you.

Comment: You may have your firewall blocking outside (outside of the local machine itself) connections to that machine. To test, disable the firewall to see of that works. If it does, reenable the firewall and adjust it to allow connection on port 80/allow iis service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Firewall is probably in the way. Make sure you have the correct exceptions made for IIS.

Go to Control Panel and allow the "internet information services" through.

If you think the Firewall is not the culprit, try using something like [nmap](http://nmap.org/) from another system on the network to poke at port 80.